# Help with getting an output from some calculations

Tags: programming

I entered the following from @Rahul's answer in "[Help with finding the point(s) inside a closed shape with the highest average ray length?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-with-finding-the-points-inside-a-closed-shape-with-the-highest-average-ra)" below my post. He told me I should enter his data one input at a time. The problem is I could not get a numerical number from my final input. Rahul believe there was problem with my computer. Here is the [link to my calculations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/54270329-fef4-44d5-b030-fda76fcee850)

In my first input tab I placed

```
curve = 
  DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}]]
```

Where I got a picture of the curve as in @Rahul's answer.

Then in my second input tab I placed

```
q = MeshCoordinates[curve];
edges = First /@ MeshCells[curve, 1];
signedAngle[a_, b_] := Arg[(Complex @@ a)/(Complex @@ b)]
avgRadius[p_] := 
  1/(2 π) Abs[
    Sum[
      Module[{q1, q2, r, dθ}, 
        q1 = q[[First @ e]]; 
        q2 = q[[Last @ e]]; 
        (* midpoint approximation *)
        r = EuclideanDistance[p, (q1 + q2)/2];
        dθ = signedAngle[q1 - p, q2 - p]; 
        r dθ], 
      {e, edges}]]
```

Finally in the third input tab I placed the following (**but got the output** in (**) to be).

```
avgRadius[{0, 0}]
(* avgRadius[{0,0}] *)
```

In my original post, I asked if someone could reply but it has been days and no one has said anything. Is there a possible way of getting a numerical output from my calculations? Is there something wrong with my computer?

Comment: The indentation of the lines following `q = ...` implies that some of your definitions are running together. Terminate each definition with `;` to insure that there is no parsing mistake. `avgRadius[{0, 0}]` then returns `1.99725`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Could you show where exactly to place the semicolons I have tried doing this and still could not get any results.

Comment: There will be no trouble if you start with a fresh kernel and evaluate each[`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and[`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in a separate cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}]]
```

[image]

```
q = MeshCoordinates[curve];

edges = First /@ MeshCells[curve, 1];

signedAngle[a_, b_] := Arg[(Complex @@ a)/(Complex @@ b)];

avgRadius[p_] := 1/(2 π) Abs[
    Sum[
     Module[{q1, q2, r, dθ},
      q1 = q[[First@e]];
      q2 = q[[Last@e]];
      r = EuclideanDistance[p, (q1 + q2)/2]; (* midpoint approximation *)
      dθ = signedAngle[q1 - p, q2 - p];
      r dθ],
     {e, edges}]];

avgRadius[{0, 0}]

(*  1.99725  *)
```