# How to apply $\overline{r}(x,y)$ to shapes with straight lines or absolute values?

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

I am studying the maxima of function $\overline{r}(x,y)$ of closed shapes.

> Suppose the curve is star-shaped with respect to this center point
>   $\mathbf p=(u,v)$, so that any ray emanating from $\mathbf p$ meets
>   the curve exactly once, at say point $\mathbf q$. Then $r = \|\mathbf
>  q - \mathbf p\|$, $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf q-\mathbf p$
>    and the $x$-axis, $\overline{r}(x,y)$ is the average radius 
>    $$\overline{r}(x,y)=\frac1{2\pi}\oint_{\mathbf q\in\mathcal C}\|\mathbf q-\mathbf
>  p\|\,\mathrm d\theta.$$
>
> and $\mathbf{p}$ is the point maximizing $\overline{r}$.
>
> (Conveniently, this integral can also be
>   computed for non-star-shaped curves; for a ray that meets the curve
>   multiple times, it amounts to taking the total length of all segments
>   that lie in the interior of the curve.)

In a [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-finding-the-points-inside-non-star-closed-shape-with-the-highest-averag), using Mesh Coordinates, Discretization, and Euler's Distance, I could calculate the maxima $\mathbf{p}$ of $\overline{r}(x,y)$.

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[
       S1[x, y] == 1, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}}], {{-3, 3}, {-4, 4}}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 8]
    q = MeshCoordinates[curve];
    edges = First /@ MeshCells[curve, 1];
    signedAngle[a_, b_] := Arg[(Complex @@ a)/(Complex @@ b)]
    avgRadius[p_] := 
     1/(2 \[Pi]) Abs[Sum[Module[{q1, q2, r, d\[Theta]}, q1 = q[[First@e]];
         q2 = q[[Last@e]];
         r = EuclideanDistance[p, (q1 + q2)/2];(*midpoint approximation*)
         d\[Theta] = signedAngle[q1 - p, q2 - p];
         r d\[Theta]], {e, edges}]]
    s = FindMaximum[avgRadius[{x, y}], {{x, 0}, {y, 0}}]
```

However, I wanted to apply a similar definition to closed shapes that contain straight lines.

---

**Shapes With Straight Lines: Polygons**

For example, for a triangle with vertices $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, if I apply `DescritizeRegion`

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
  Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}]], {{-1, 1}, {-1, 
    1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

instead of showing the discretized region it gives the following.

> ```
> DiscretizeRegion::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of DiscretizeRegion[,{{-1,1},{-1,1}},AccuracyGoal->8].
> ```

Assuming the positions should be labelled, I used `BoundaryMeshRegion`

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
  BoundaryMeshRegion[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
   Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]], {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

but instead of descritizing the boundary, its descritizes the area.

[image]

How do I apply $\overline{r}(x,y)$ to the triangle? Similarily how would apply this to a dumbell shaped curve?

[image]

Comment: Note that `Graphics` is not a _region_. You can discretize the 1-dimensional line by removing the `Graphics[...]` and just using `DiscretizeRegion[
  Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}], AccuracyGoal -> 8]`.

Comment: @eyorble I tried that but I get `DiscretizeRegion::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of DiscretizeRegion[Line[{-1,0},{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0}],{{-2,2},{-2,2}},AccuracyGoal->4].`

Comment: As far a I know, there is no dedicated method in Mathematica to discretize a non-fulldimensional `MeshRegion`. However, even being not the most efficient way and having requirement that the curve has to be closed, you can use `curve = BoundaryMesh@
  DiscretizeRegion[
   BoundaryMeshRegion[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
    Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]], {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}]`

Comment: @Arbuja `Line[{-1,0},{0,1},...]` is not a valid line: `Line` takes a list of points (i.e. `Line[{ {-1,0}, {0,1} ... }]`, note the extra `{}`). Also what is the `{{-2,2},{-2,2}}`? A region specification doesn't take anything like a `PlotRegion` specification, but if you're trying to do something else please clarify that.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I get an the image of blue triangle but when I apply the code for $\mathbf{r}(x,y)$ (MeshCoordinates,Descritzation,Signed Angle,Module...) I get `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. +0. I) encountered` and `Arg::indet: Indeterminate expression Arg[ComplexInfinity] encountered.`

Comment: That's  not an issue of the discretization but of division by zero. That happens because the initial guess for `FindMinimum` is `{0,0}` which happens to lie on the curve. Try `s = FindMaximum[avgRadius[{x, y}], {{x, 0.1}, {y, 0.1}}]` instead.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I tried that and it gives an output but the warning message `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. +0. I) encountered` and `Arg::indet: Indeterminate expression Arg[ComplexInfinity] ` remains.

Comment: Moreover I used `AccuracyGoal->8` but it continues to give a low accuracy of `{0.543361, {x -> 0.00014495, y -> 0.375155}}`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I apologize if I'm sending too many comments but I think the code is giving the incorrect answer. The maximum point $\mathbf{p}$ of $\overline{r}(x,y)$ should be $(0,1/3)$.

Comment: @eyorble The `{{-2,2},{-2,2}}` specifies the region of descritization.

Comment: @Arbuja I am not sure that increaing `AccuracyGoal` in `DiscretizeRegion` is the right way to achieve higher accuracy here; the error of your method is proportional to the maximal edge length of `curve`. You can control the maximal edge length with `MaxCellMeasure->{1->len}` (1 stands for 1-dimensional cells, `len` for the maximal length you allow). Anyway, using `DiscretizeRegion` and applying `BoundaryMesh` on the result is a very expensive way to get a finely smapled curve. See my aanswer below for a more performant approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to specify a one-dimensional region:

```
γ = t \[Function] {Cos[t], Sin[t]} (1. + 0.25 Sin[5 t]);
n = 1000;
pts = Table[γ[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}];
curve = MeshRegion[pts, Line[Transpose[{Range[1, n], Range[2, n + 1]}]]];
```

It circumvents the need for `DiscretizeRegion`. You can adapt that also for triangles: Simply parameterize and sample the boundary pieces and use `Join` to create a single list of points. Your procedure for finding the point of maximal avarage ray length will work quite likely on regions defined this way.

Comment: @HendrickSchumacer You can’t use any parametrization. For example, consider a ellipse with parametric curve $(2\cos{(t)},3\sin({t}))$ gives a different average distance then $(\frac{6\cos{(t)}}{\sqrt{4\cos^{2}(t)+9\sin^{2}(t)}},\frac{6\sin{(t)}}{\sqrt{4\cos^{2}(t)+9\sin^{2}(t)}})$

Comment: @Arbuja Why on earth should the average distance (or average ray length) depend on the parameterization parameter `t`? Really, could you please think about the problem a bit more thoroughly before asking the next time?

Comment: @HenrikSchmacer I never said the average distance must depend on t. What I'm saying is if you parameterize the curve, the distance formula of some parametrizations give the incorrect average radius.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacer How come you graphed $r=1+0.25\sin{(5\theta)}$. Can your code work for non-polar equations.

Comment: @Arbuja This may work for any other sufficiently smooth and regular curve. I chose to use a curve in polar coordinates just for convenience.