# Unable to Solve Area Using Paramteric Equations derived from The Numeric Soution of a Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, interpolation

I'm creating a test that measures the distribution of closed shape $\mathcal{C}$. This requires taking the average ray length (from $(u,v)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to the boundary) using ray length per radian measure.

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ can be described as $(a_1(t),a_2(t))$. If $\overline{r}(u,v)$ is the average radius, the distrbution number is

$$\phi(u,v)=\frac{1}{\overline{r}(u,v)}\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(
\left|\sqrt{\left(a_1(t)-u\right)^2+\left(a_2(t)-v\right)^2}-\overline{r}(u,v)\right|\frac{d\theta}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a_2(t)-u}{a_1(t)-v}\right)\right)
\right)dt$$

Where $t_1<t<t_2$ parametrizes the entire region

There is no clear way of determining where to measure $(u,v)$. Hence I took the average of $\phi(u,v)$ for all $(u,v)$ in $\mathcal{C}$. This leads to a difficult formula.

$$\omega=\frac{1}{\text{Area}\left(\mathcal{C}\right)} \iint\limits_{C} \phi(u,v) \ du \ dv$$

In this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163626/34171), I can parametrize any implicitly defined $\mathcal{C}$ using arclength.  In this example, $\mathcal{C}$ is $\left(x^2 + y^2 +\sin(4 x) + \sin(4 y) - 4\right)^2 + .415 x=.4$

```
expr = (x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] - 4)^2 + .415 x - .4;
exprt = expr /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]};
odes = {D[exprt, t], x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 - 1}
starty = y /. FindRoot[(expr /. x -> 0) == 0, {y, 2/9}]
Quiet[soln = 
   NDSolveValue[
    Join[Thread[odes == 0], {x[0] == 0, y[0] == starty}], {x[t], 
     y[t]}, {t, 0, 25}];]
{solnX, solnY} = soln;
ParametricPlot[soln, {t, 0, 25}]
Plot[(solnX - 0)^2 + (solnY - starty)^2, {t, 0, 25}]
{min, val} = NMinimize[(solnX - 0)^2 + (solnY - starty)^2, {t, 20, 25}]
stopt = t /. val;
r = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
  NIntegrate[
    Sqrt[(solnX - x)^2 + (solnY - y)^2]*
     D[ArcTan[solnX - x, solnY - y], t], {t, 0, stopt}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 100, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]/(2*Pi)]

s = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
  NIntegrate[
    Abs[Sqrt[(solnX - x)^2 + (solnY - y)^2] - r[x, y]]*
     D[ArcTan[solnX - x, solnY - y], t], {t, 0, stopt}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 100, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]/(2*Pi)]
```

The distrbution number is

```
Phi = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, s[x, y]/r[x, y]]
```

The problems is I'm unable to use the code in the following ways.

<s>1. I can't extract values from `solnX` and `solnY`. I tried `solnX[1]`, `solnX[][1]` and `sol[{{0.,25.}}][1]`. (Note these are not "typical" interpolation formulas, they're composed of two parts: the domain output and `t`.)</s> This was fixed in the comments below.

2. <s>I cant graph</s>  Graphing `Phi[x,y]` takes too long.
3. I can't solve for the area using `Integrate[D[solnX,t]*solY,{t,0,stopt}]`

Without these, I cannot compute $\omega$.

Comment: have you tried to make this work without monkeying around with `Compile` ?

Comment: @george2079 I tried without Compile, it didn't work.

Comment: @george2079 The main problem is with `SolnX` and `SolnY`

Comment: do like this: `soln[t_] = NDSolveValue...` , then `soln[1]` -> `{-0.54648, 2.12265}`  or you could do `{solnX[t_], solnY[t_]} = soln` with `soln` the way you have it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @george2079 I'm unable to integrate using parametric equations. The derivative of interpolated functions is difficult to calculate.